# Is there a way to return custom struct from a function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, data-structures, struct, return-type

I wanted to know if it were possible to somehow return a custom struct from a function.

Actual use case: I have a dictionary in the form of a string, separated by some separator. Eg: a FIX message: "8=FIX.4.4,8=MKT...", while parsing this message, I want to have these key-value pairs extracted, ideally in a form of a struct: {8:FIX.4.4..}, can I have a single universal function for all messages? what data structure can be a possible return type?

The use case seems to be a fit for maps, but as the type of all the values can be different, I ruled it out. I want to get the data in their respective types, ie, int as int, string as string, seeing the key I can predetermine the expected type, eg: 34 is expected to be an integer, 8 is expected to be a string, etc. It will be great if you guys can share any ideas you have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> fooFunction(std::pair<int, int> input);

Comment: Not really clear what the problem is or what you are asking. You want to return different types from the same function depending on some condition? Then you need some kind of type erasure, like `std::any` or `std::variant`. But there might be better options if you explain your use case.

Comment: [Sounds like an XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: *but as the type of all the values can be different* Please clarify. It sounds like they can be represented as strings at least. So if you have some other idea you should explain it instead of letting us guess. I'm guessing you want something other then a `std::map<int, std::string>`?

Comment: I want to get the data in their respective types, ie, int as int, string as string, seeing the key I can predermine the expected type @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: @DEEPANSHNAGARIA -- Let's say you come up with this "struct".   What do you do with this data *after* you've created it?  How do you determine what the data type is from this "struct"?   A data type is only known at compile time in C++.  Have you thought about this through the entire process?

Comment: You basically want a JavaScript-Object, right? You can get close to this with `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any>` (or the ordered variant `std::map<...>`). But it will be quite hard to work with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comment, you can store your data in a map of variants:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <variant>
using std::cout, std::endl;

using var_t = std::variant<int, std::string, float, double>;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, var_t> myMap {
        { 10,  "hello world" },
        { 1,   5 },
        { 25,  1.0f },
        { 100, -8e20 },
    };

    // 1
    for (const auto& [key, value]: myMap) {
        cout << "[" << key << ": ";
        if (auto i_ptr = std::get_if<int>(&value)) {
            cout << *i_ptr;
        } else if (auto str_ptr = std::get_if<std::string>(&value)) {
            cout << *str_ptr;
        } else if (auto f_ptr = std::get_if<float>(&value)) {
            cout << *f_ptr;
        } else if (auto d_ptr = std::get_if<double>(&value)) {
            cout << *d_ptr;
        }
        cout << "]\n";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    // 2
    for (const auto& [key, value]: myMap) {
        std::visit([&key](auto& v) {
            cout << "[" << key << ": " << v << "]\n";
        }, value);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1PhYfq4hs

To access your data once it's stored in a variant, you can

1. test for each potential type with `std::get_if`. Using `std::hold_alternative` + `std::get` is also an option.

or

2. make a visitor (the lambda) and pass it to `std::visit` along your variant

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/

Answer (score -1):

Being a compiled language you cannot make type decisions at runtime, based on data. Therefore the key question is what you know about the types when the code is compiled.

- If you know the exact types, this is just a templated function
- If you know a list of possible types at compile time, this is a map<variant,variant> problem
- If the types are potentially composed of other types, then you are looking at using a library (like JSON)

So, the most generic solution would be to return a [JSON document](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html). As long as the data you want can be represented as JSON. [Other libraries are also available](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp)

A more native way is to use [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant#:%7E:text=A%20variant%20is%20not%20permitted%20to%20hold%20references%2C,hold%20differently%20cv-qualified%20versions%20of%20the%20same%20type.) which allows you to say "this is complete list of possible types" (at compile time). Which type is actually used can be decided when the file is read.

---- BUT ----

Be aware that one of the basic laws of computing, is that the more things your program can do, the more complex it will be. A common rule of thumb, is that the *best* you can do, is to keep the complexity to the square of the number of features. So a map<variant<int,float>, variant<int,float>> is 4 times harder to write than map<type1,type2>.
Adding JSON handling, means you inject an infinite number of types. This means you can never test all possible types. Your program is now impossible to test! In practice, when you handle things like JSON documents, the first thing you do, is reject documents that do not fit some criteria, restricting the number of legal types you have to handle, making testing possible again.